# Can I use OpenGL ES in a Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: opengl-es, windows-phone-8

I've read places that Windows Phone 8 will not support OpenGL, and I'm unable to find anything useful in the SDK.

So am I or will I ever be able to use OpenGL (ES) in my Windows Phone 8 game? I have a game I would like not to rewrite completely to DirectX when porting.

Please cite good sources, the only thing I've found are speculations and blog posts with little to no information.

Comment: To be properly supported OpenGL needs a graphics driver with an OpenGL ICD module. Since Microsoft is tightly in control of tablet hardware, (the Surface RT e.g.) and ever since Windows Vista tries everything in their power to limit OpenGL functionality, its very unlikely that there will be proper OpenGL support on Windows 8 tablets. Just my estimation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OpenGL isn't supported on WP8, but Direct 3D feature level 9_3 is supported. If you're looking to port over a game from OpenGL ES over to D3D have a look at the [Angle Project](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/). Angle Project helps bridge the gap between OpenGL ES 2.0 and D3D 9. It doesn't have WP8 targeting just yet and you'll have issues with runtime compile shaders not being supported on WP8, but Angle project is still a good first step.

Either way, for games portability with other platforms it's really best if you work with a middleware gaming framework such as MonoGame, Unity, Cocos2D, Havok, Marmalade, SharpDX, Ogre, Autodesk Scaleform or others. These engines will mostly handle cross platform support for you within their own framework (each with it's own limitations on code and assets portability).

If you already have an existing OpenGL game you want to port over to WP8, than Angle project if your best bet going forward. If you're just starting out creating a cross-platform portable game than choosing a gaming middleware framework that seems right for your game's needs is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any significant sources?

Comment: I have no official publication or significant source stating that Windows Phone cannot make coffee, but I can bet you it's true. If OpenGL was supported, Microsoft would have mentioned it in the SDK documentation and during the Build conferences.

Comment: I'm the Principal Engineer for Windows Phone Developer Experience at Nokia. I'm my own sources :)

Comment: I don't clearly see the benefits of using AngleProject. Angle is mainly working on top of D3D9 and WP8 is only providing D3D11 API. The part of Angle that could be used is their GLSL to HLSL translator, though the generated HLSL is in SM2.0/SM3.0 old syntax while D3D11 on WP8 is requiring SM4.0 syntax.

Comment: WP8 is D3D11 with feature level 9_3, there is no D3D9 API. Angle Project is only working with straight D3D9 API/shaders and not D3D11 level 9_3. Check this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2012/10/30/apollo-has-landed.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Marmalade does let you write OpenGL ES 2.0 code and make it work in Windows phone 8 without making you do anything

Check this for more details:
http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/windows-phone-8

Answer (score 0):

Even if Windows Phone 8 supported OpenGL (which it doesn't), it would support OpenGL ES, not destkop OpenGL. Since it's for embedded platforms.

So that's no twice.

Comment: By OpenGL I meant the entire family.

Answer (score 0):

[Gideros](http://giderosmobile.com/) uses OpenGL and targets Windows RT/Phone graphics by means of a lightweight DX wrapper.