# Use of OpenGL in Windows phone 8

Tags: opengl-es, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing an app for windows phone 8 I want to use OpenGl like in android and iOS I searched in internet but not found stuff that is helpful for me please suggest me if it is possible for WP8?

Comment: Related question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483179/can-i-use-opengl-es-in-a-windows-phone-8-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483179/can-i-use-opengl-es-in-a-windows-phone-8-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenGL is not supported on Windows Phone. You can use Direct3D in Windows Phone 8 or XNA in Windows Phone 7/8.

EDIT/UPDATE:

If you want to use OpenGL on Windows Phone 8, you can use the [ANGLE](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) project which is an OpenGL API built on top of DirectX.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is not supported *yet* on Windows Phone, but according to Marmalade, they will be providing OpenGL ES for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 "in early 2013".

Read their announcement at the following link and download Marmalade to get notified when it becomes available:
http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/windows8?utm_source=fronpage-carousel&utm_medium=site-internal&utm_campaign=windows8-announce

Note that Marmalade is not free though - even the Community Edition is $149/seat/year..

Comment: Marmalade apparently released a new version (6.2.1) this past week and it has Visual Studio 2012 integration and Beta support for developing Windows Phone 8 games with OpenGL ES 2.0! See here:
http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/windows-phone-8